# Can't do multiple name-field POST with Node.js on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, heroku

I am developing a web app with Node.js. I write a hidden form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to upload a file and some texts, but it acts strangely that I can only get one field (name in the form) on the herokuapp server rather than multiple fields I want.

The client side code is like :

```
<form action="/target" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input hidden type="file" name="file" id="file">
   <input hidden type="text" name="A" id="A" value="AAA">
   <input hidden type="text" name="B" id="B" value="BBB">
   <input hidden type="text" name="C" id="C" value="CCC">
   <input hidden type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And the server side code is like :

```
app.post('/target', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.files.file.path);
    console.log(req.body.A);
    console.log(req.body.B);
    console.log(req.body.C);
    res.end();
})
```

I can only get `req.body.C` with the other 2 remaining `undefined`, but it works totally fine when I run on localhost.
I use [multer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer) to handle the multipart form with configuration:

```
app.use(multer({dest:'./public/uploads/'}))
```

Comment: I am having the exact same problem - a form with multiple hidden values. Under localhosts it works fine - under localhosts with NODE_ENV=production it works fine. However, the moment I deploy to Heroku req.body fails - but req.query is fine. I am also using Multer so I can pull out file info. The file stuff works... its just req.body that fails.

Answer (score 0):

Please run your server locally with the environment variable `NODE_ENV=production`. This will run your server as if it was running in production. Then try to reproduce this issue.

One other thing to consider is which Express version you're using. Express 4 does not come with a [body parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware anymore; you have to bring it in yourself.

Apologies for making suggestions as an answer. I don't have the reputation required to allow me to comment yet.

Comment: I'm using express 4 and this is the [link](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) to the bodyParser I use

Comment: Where you able to run your server locally with `NODE_ENV=production`? Also, double check the order you `.use` your middleware.

Comment: Ok - so I was using cloudinary... In the end I did a direct upload from the browser. For some unknown reason, multer appears to be blocking body-parser. I don't know why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has a readonly file system. The directory where you can write are ./tmp or ./log. try that, good luck !